# Apache Phoenix LIMIT OFFSET Error

Tags: apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

I need to know what the error means and how to debug it.
Here is what I did.

Query1:

```
SELECT * FROM us_population ORDER BY population DESC;
```

Result1:

```
NY  New York        8143197
CA  Los Angeles     3844829
IL  Chicago         2842518
TX  Houston         2016582
PA  Philadelphia    1463281
AZ  Phoenix         1461575
TX  San Antonio     1256509
CA  San Diego       1255540
TX  Dallas          1213825
CA  San Jose        912332
```

Query2:

```
SELECT * FROM us_population ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Result2:

```
NY  New York        8143197
CA  Los Angeles     3844829
IL  Chicago         2842518
TX  Houston         2016582
PA  Philadelphia    1463281
```

Query3:

```
SELECT * FROM us_population ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

Result3:

```
Error: Error -1 (00000) : Error while executing SQL "SELECT * FROM vhen_test_population ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5": Remote driver error: RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 602 (42P00): Syntax error. Missing "EOF" at line 1, column 69. -> PhoenixParserException: ERROR 602 (42P00): Syntax error. Missing "EOF" at line 1, column 69. -> MissingTokenException: (null exception message)
SQLState:  00000
ErrorCode: -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of Phoenix,

Version 4.8.0 has Offset Support for Paged Queries

Please Refer to https://phoenix.apache.org/paged.html